# Listar os meses, por ano em mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou a tentar fazer o seguinte em `php` e `mysql`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que está entre parênteses é o número de resultados dentro de cada mês. Para tal, estou a guardar na minha base de dados, na tabela `tbl_noticias` o campo `data` do tipo `yyyy-mm-dd`. Estou a guardar ainda o campo `id` entre outros(não preciso para aqui). Não estou a conseguir perceber como posso chegar a este resultado final usando o mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui lá chegar do seguinte modo:

```
<?php
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(data) AS ano, id AS id FROM tbl_noticias GROUP BY ano");
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
                    {
                        $ano = $row['ano'];
                        echo "Ano: ".$ano."<br>";
                        $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(data) AS mes, id AS id FROM tbl_noticias WHERE YEAR(data) = '$ano' GROUP BY mes");
                        while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
                        {
                            $mes = $row1['mes'];
                            echo "Mes: ".$mes." - ";
                            $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS contagem FROM tbl_noticias WHERE YEAR(data) = '$ano' AND MONTH(data) = '$mes'");
                            $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
                            echo $row2['contagem']."<br>";
                        }
                    }
                  ?>
```

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

tenta usar está lógica ou até mesmo o código

```
$query=mysql_query("SELECT data, DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y') as ano FROM tbl_noticias GROUP BY YEAR(data)");

$anos_meses="";
while ($row_anos = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
    $ano = $row_anos["ano"];
    $anos_meses[]=$ano;

    $buscar_meses=mysql_query("SELECT data, DATE_FORMAT(data,'%M') as mes FROM tbl_noticias WHERE YEAR(data)='$ano' GROUP BY MONTH(data)");
    while ($row_meses = mysql_fetch_assoc($buscar_meses)) 
    {
        $mes=$row_meses['mes'];
        $anos_meses[$ano][]=$mes;
    }
}

print_r($anos_meses);
```

Comment: entretanto consegui chegar ao resultado com a resposta que meti. de qualquer modo obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

@pc_oc Se utilizar uma consulta a cada iteração apenas para saber o total (COUNT(*) AS contagem) terá grande problema com desempenho e consumo de memória, em especial se a tabela for diferente de MyISAM.

Pode usar COUNT(*) na segunda consulta, sem necessidade de uma 3.a consulta:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(data) AS ano, id AS id FROM tbl_noticias GROUP BY ano");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    echo "Ano: {$row['ano']}<br>";
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT MONTH(data) AS mes, COUNT(*) AS contagem, id FROM tbl_noticias WHERE YEAR(data) = '$ano' GROUP BY mes");
    while ( ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))) {
        echo "Mes: {$row1['mes']} - ({$row1['contagem']})<br>";
    }
}
```

No seu exemplo, o PHP chamará a função COUNT(*) 15 vezes, ao passo que nesta, chamará apenas 2 vezes.